# Change Item-level analysis to participant-level analysis

Tags: r, dplyr

So here's a reproducible sample of my dataset.

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 100
dat <- data.frame(Participant=1:20, 
                  Environment=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                  Condition=rep(LETTERS[25:26], n/2),
                  Gate= sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE),
                  Block = sample(1:2, n, replace=TRUE),
                  Sound=rep(LETTERS[3:4], n/2),
                  Correct=sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE)
)
```

When I calculate the standard error of this table,

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(Condition, Gate, Sound) %>% 
  summarize(Accuracy = mean(Correct),
            se = sd(Correct)/sqrt(length(Correct)))
```

it analyzes at the item-level(trial). I was hoping to transform the dataset to a more condensed version, where it groups data for each participant. For example, I would want to be able to see each participant's individual performance on Gate 1 in Condition Y with C sound. Here is an example to make it less abstract:

[image]

Here is an example of the code I use for graphs:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(Condition, Gate, Sound) %>% 
  summarize(Accuracy = mean(Correct),
            se = sd(Correct)/sqrt(length(Correct)))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Gate, y = Accuracy, color = Sound, group = Sound)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Accuracy - se, ymax = Accuracy + se), color = "Black", size = .15, width = .3) +
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

and I get a graph like this:

[image]

If I group by participant with this code:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(Condition, Gate, Sound,Participant) %>% 
  summarize(Accuracy = mean(Correct),
            se = sd(Correct)/sqrt(length(Correct)))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Gate, y = Accuracy, color = Sound, group = Sound)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Accuracy - se, ymax = Accuracy + se), color = "Black", size = .15, width = .3) +
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

I get a graph like this:

[image]

Which does not work. So I think I need to create a new dataset in R like the sample above(image 1), before conducting analysis. Maybe I could use the subset function to accomplish this somehow, like this:

```
participant_dat = subset(dat, ...) #Not sure where to go from here.
```

Comment: 1. Your code as written throws errors.
2. If I understand what you want, you can just add `Participant` to your `group_by()`. But you obviously won't be able to compute se for Participant/Gate/Condition/etc combinations with <2 rows.

Comment: I tried that, and it throws off my graphs. I’m more looking to transform the dataset to a condense version for further analysis. The code above should work now

Comment: I understand "a more condensed version" to mean you want to have a single row for each unique combination of Participant / Gate / Condition / etc. If that is what you want, then grouping by those variables and then summarizing would be the clearest way to do it -- if that isn't producing what you want, can you edit your post to show the problem? e.g., how is it "throwing off your graphs"? If that's *not* what you mean by "a more condensed version," can you clarify what you do mean?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

To get what I wanted, I grouped my data by participant using this code:

```
Participant_Data<- dat%>% 
  group_by(Condition, Gate, Sound, **Participant**) %>% 
  summarize(Accuracy = mean(Correct), 
            se = sd(Correct)/sqrt(length(Correct)))
```

Then I used the below code to plot a graph based on the condensed dataset.

```
Participant_Data%>% 
  group_by(Condition, Gate, Sound) %>%
  summarize(Proportion_Correct = mean(**Accuracy**), #finding the mean of each participant's accuracy
            standarderror = sd(Accuracy)/sqrt(length(Accuracy))) %>% #calculating standard error for participant accuracy (participant-level), and not trial accuracy(item-level)
  ggplot(aes(x = Gate, y = Proportion_Correct, color = Sound, group = Sound)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Proportion_Correct - standarderror, ymax = Proportion_Correct + standarderror), color = "Black", size = .15, width = .3) + #plotting error bars for each participant, not for each item
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
  facet_wrap(~Condition) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```